# How to change jaxb model for add inner list of elements?

Tags: spring, jaxb

I use spring for creation rest-controller and jaxb lib for exchangin with client xml - elements, so, my model are Users, User and Property.
Users contains list of users, every user contains list of properies. To create Users with user-list elements - it works, but can't to create inner property-list for user elements.

My models are:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Users {
    @XmlElement(name = "User")
    private List<User> users;

    @XmlElement(name = "UserError")
    private UserError error;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "Property")
    private List<Property> properties;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "Property")
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Property implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name = "passport")
    private String passport;

    @XmlElement(name = "age")
    private String age;
}
```

How to change jaxb model for change xml from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
    <User>
        <Id>fff</Id>
        <Name>Alex</Name>
        <Property>
           <Name>passport</Name>
           <Value>111-222</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
           <Name>car</Name>
           <Value>bmv</Value>
        </Property>
    </User>
</Users>
```

To this view presentation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
    <User>
        <Id>fff</Id>
        <Name>Alex</Name>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <Name>passport</Name>
                <Value>111-222</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <Name>car</Name>
                <Value>bmv</Value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. Just add an [`@XmlElementWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) annotation to the definition of
the Java variable `properties`:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Properties")
@XmlElement(name = "Property")
private List<Property> properties;
```

This will add `<Properties>...</Properties>` around the sequence of `<Property>...</Property>` elements.